# Replacing pending deploy tx with truffle

Tags: solidity, truffle

I deployed my contract with default params using `truffle migrate --network mainnet --reset` the gas was too low and got my tx pending for more than 20 hours already. I wanted to replace the tx with new one and dropping the old tx. How do I do it on truffle? My new `truffle-config.js` is this:

```
mainnet: {
      provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(
        process.env.PRIVATE_KEY, 
        process.env.NODE_URL
      ),
      network_id: 1,       //mainnet 
      gasPrice: 75000000000
    },
```

Is there a way to set the nonce there to drop and replace the tx?